# Understanding multiple keys with WPF KeyDown event

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-events

I'm using WPF `KeyDown` event. Can you please explain why this condition is true, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>? When I press <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is already pressed so `!Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)` should be false.

**Edit:**

In the code below if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> both messages would fire. But if you change the order of these two if statements, only "ctrlF1" message would fire like it should be. I would like to get explanation of that strange behavior.

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F1 && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ctrlF1");
    }
    if (e.Key == Key.F1 && !Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("F1");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested and it works for me. Are you really holding the **left** Ctrl key?

Comment: You could perhaps try this line: `if (e.Key == Key.F1 && (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == 0)`

Comment: @FlatEric sorry, I localized problem and change the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is as follows:

- In the code you showed, when entering the handler, <kbd>F1</kbd> is pressed and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed (both conditions of first if-clause are true). MessageBox blocks the thread. Meanwhile you release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and click at the message. Then code execution goes on and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is no longer pressed (both conditions of the second if-clause are true)
- If you switch the if-statements, only the first condition (`e.Key == Key.F1`) of the first if-statement is true. Execution comes to second if-statement and both conditions are true. MessageBox is shown and execution stops till the MessageBox is closed.

The difference is: Pressing of the <kbd>F1</kbd> key is evaluated before the handler is called, but the check `Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl)` is evaluated in the moment, when the line of code is executed

Comment: @Dork To add to this, if you simply want to test something when handling input, use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("message")` to print a message to the debugger output window rather than doing something that  requires interaction like showing a message box or hitting a breakpoint. Then you can be sure the input state doesn't change while you are trying to observe it.