# How to Disable LWin and Arrow shortcut in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-events

In my application I have a loading screen that is supposed to cover the whole screen (logo omitted):
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8am3y.png)

My view is composed of a StackPanel (for the logo and some text) contained within a Grid. It is displayed using the Window.Show() from the System.Windows library.

```
var popup = new Window()
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Maximized,
            WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
            AllowsTransparency = true,
            Visibility = Visibility.Visible,
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
            Content = loaderMvvmSet.View, 
            IsHitTestVisible = true,
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White) { Opacity = 0.1 },
            Topmost = true,
            ShowInTaskbar = false
        };
```

When testing, we noticed that the user could bypass the loading screen using key combinations: `Window` + `Arrow`. To disable this resizing, I set `ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize`. This seems to have worked for clicking `Windows` + `Up / Right / Left`. However, when I click `Windows` + `Down` I get this: [Actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFcWE.png)

I checked out other posts but have not been able to find a solution to my problem. Here is what I tried:

**1. Attaching an event handler to the KeyDown event:**

a. Setting the Handled property to true for each key separately:

```
    private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.LWin)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

b. Checking that both keys are pressed and setting the Handled property to true:

```
    private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.LWin && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Down))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

c. Creating separate Booleans for the both keys and then if both are set to true, the event is ignored.

**2. Added KeyBindings to the Window and giving it an empty command:**

a. Using the Modifiers and the Key:

```
InputBindings = { new KeyBinding() { Modifiers = ModifierKeys.Windows, Key = Key.Down, Command = EmptyCommand } }
```

b. Using just the `Down` Key:

```
InputBindings = { new KeyBinding() { Key = Key.Down, Command = EmptyCommand } }
```

What I noticed for point 1 is that the KeyDown event gets fired for the `Windows` key but not for the `Down` key. It seems like as long as I am still holding the Windows key, the `Down` key is never acknowledged. 
For point 2, having both the Modifiers and the Key (point a) does not seem to work at all; my breakpoint in the `EmptyCommand` is never hit. And, having just the `Down` Key (point b) seems like the same issue as in point 1, that it will fire for a KeyBinding with just the `LWin` key, but does not get acknowledged for the `Down` key (because we are still holding `LWin`).

Here are some of the links I have checked:

[How to detect multiple keys down onkeydown event in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013087/how-to-detect-multiple-keys-down-onkeydown-event-in-wpf)

[Understanding multiple keys with WPF KeyDown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942875/understanding-multiple-keys-with-wpf-keydown-event)

Comment: Welcome! This is a thoughtful question and the inclusion of techniques you tried makes it easier for other contributors to help out.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an ideal solution, but if LWin + Down (Restore Down) triggers a size changed event, perhaps you can force reset the window state?

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.resize?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1

XAML:
   `SizeChanged="MyLoaderView_OnSizeChanged"`

Code-Behind:

```
private void MyLoaderView_OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Window window = (Window)sender;
    window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: This solution seems to have worked for the most part. However, when clicking `Windows` + `Down` the window will sort of flicker between the smaller version and maximized, whereas `Windows` + `Up \ Right \ Left` are not registered at all with `ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be definitely solved with keyboard hooker. Capture the win+arraws combination keys and handle that.

With [TonyValenti's powerful native hook package](https://github.com/MediatedCommunications/WindowsInput), I wrote code below.

```cs
var KeyboardDisposable = WindowsInput.Capture.Global.KeyboardAsync();
var Listener = new KeyChordEventSource(Keyboard, new ChordClick(KeyCode.LWin, KeyCode.Left));
Listener.Triggered += (s, e) =>
{
    if (User32.GetForegroundWindow() == WpfWindowHandle)
    {
        e.Input.Next_Hook_Enabled = false;
    }
};
Listener.Enabled = true;
```

Remember dispose keyboard or listener to avoid memory leak.